# Deleting objects in different thread causes crash?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I have a main thread that I create some self-contained class instances in.

The instances themselves contain a lot of data, and need to be deleted and recreated often. The actual deletion of them takes a while (100k instances containing a lot of data == long deletion time), so I had the idea of just offloading the deletion of them to a separate thread and therefore allowing the UI to stay responsive while they are being deleted and memory is cleaned up.

Here's some pseudocode showing the class I want to delete:

```
class myObj
{
    std::vector<int> bigData; //eventually filled with lots of data
};
```

Here's some pseudocode to show how the default blocking deletion method works:

```
void deleteStuff (std::vector<myObj*> *objects) //this works fine
{
    for (auto obj : *objects)
    {
        delete obj;
    }
    objects->clear();
}
```

But when I delete things this way, my program crashes. Why?

```
void deleteStuffThreaded(std::vector<myObj*> *objects)
{
    for (auto obj : *objects)
    {
        delete obj;
    }
    objects->clear();
}

void deleteStuff(std::vector<myObj*> *objects) //this crashes
{
    std::thread deleteThread(&deleteStuffThreaded, objects);
}
```

It's worth noting that the "objects" vector is never touched again once deleteStuff returns, so it's not a race condition happening elsewhere in the code between "objects" being cleared in the thread and it being accessed elsewhere. Also sometimes the "deleteStuffThreaded" function crashes before getting to the "clear" line when I step through the code.

Google tells me it's theoretically possible to delete objects in different threads than the one they were created in, and I know the crash isn't caused by trying to access properties of one of the deleted objects after "deleteStuff" returns, because the single-threaded version works fine (and I've checked my code and those instances are never touched again).

Comment: Are any other threads using that `vector` or a copy of that `vector`? If yes, crashes are almost to be expected.

Comment: You don't appear to use any mutexes to ensure no one else is using `myObj` before deleting it. The single threaded version would work fine because there the code runs sequentially, whereas here you might call `deleteStuff` then proceed to access `myObj`

Comment: @user4581301 Nope, and I edited my question to add a note about that....that vector is never touched again (for the sake of argument, consider that even its pointer is not deleted).

Comment: @Tas I don't see why I would need a mutex....after "deleteStuff" returns, those myObj instances are never touched again. If they were, the single-threaded "deleteStuff" would also generate errors.

Comment: Any chance of a [mcve] for this sucker? I know multithreaded MCVEs are a pain in the ass, but we can't make any good statements about described code. Clearly something has been missed somewhere or it wouldn't be blowing up, and if you knew what it was and could add it to the description, you probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @user4581301 I can try to put one together....was moreso hoping I was making an obvious incorrect assumption about something that someone might know...like maybe you can't actually do cross-thread deletions or what-not.

Comment: Oh jeeze I feel embarrassed. No `join`. Yeah What he said V.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah me too...@nos was right...I'm forgetting to call join/detach (in my case, detach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::thread` destructor docs say:

> ~thread();        (since C++11)
>
> Destroys the thread object.
>
> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true),
>   std::terminate() is called.

So since you have not joined or detached the thread, the program will terminate when your `deleteStuff` function ends and the destructor of the thread object is called

Since you likely want to fire and forget about your thread, do:

```
std::thread deleteThread(&deleteStuffThreaded, objects);
deleteThread.detach();
```